# Open up the selection window for page templates within the page library

Tags: sharepoint-online, library, template, modern-pages, sitepages

When I am on the home page and create a new page, no matter how:

- "new drop-down menu" > Page
- Gear (top right) > Add page

Then I get a window where I can choose from different page templates.

[image: Templates]

However, if I am in the actual library, in this case /myPage/SitePages/ and I click on the cog to add a new page, then I don't get this selection window displayed.

**So my question is:**

How can I get this template selection mask within my page library? Or differently: how can I select one of my templates within this library?

The users' workspace is within this library, so it would be necessary for them to have access to the templates from there.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge for now we do not have such feature to display page template like that in site pages library. You may post your ideas in [uservocie](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration) for more attention from the MS team.